# attribute name of span in rangy with css

Tags: javascript, css, rangy

How  can i put the atribute name of a span in Ragy with cssApplier. One example:

```
<span name="##" id ="##" class="note">
```

i try:

```
highlighter.addCssClassApplier(rangy.createCssClassApplier("note", {
            ignoreWhiteSpace: true,
            elementTagName: ["span"],
            elementProperties: {
                name:"##",
                id:"##",
                onmousedown: function (){
                    if (event.button==2){
                    var highlight = highlighter.getHighlightForElement(this);
                    if (window.confirm("Delete this new note ?")) {
                        highlighter.removeHighlights( [highlight] );
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                }
            }
        }
```

But it doesnt work. it was a result:

```
<span  id ="##" class="note">
```

Is it a bug in rangy?

Comment: ID/Name/Class names must begin with an alphabet or underscore and should not contain any special characters.

Comment: oh yes, I've tried putting numbers and letters.But it does not work.

i try elementProperties: {
                name:"content",
                id:"one", ...  }

Comment: Which version of Rangy are you using? Which browser? A quick test on Rangy 1.3 worked fine, but I need more information. Also, you need to be aware that it is invalid in HTML for multiple elements to have the same ID, and there's no guarantee that Rangy's CSS class applier will only create one `<span>` element, so specifying an the ID in the element properties is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I use rangy-1.3alpha.681 and chrome.